# Non-dimensionalized Laplacian of Gaussian

Tags: dimensional-analysis

From the perspective of *dimensional analysis*, in the Laplacian of Gaussian operator
$$LoG(x,y,\sigma)=\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}.$$ I think $x,y$ are variables with dimension $L$, $\sigma$ is a parameter with dimension $L$. But what about $g$? Since $g$ is a function of $x,y,\sigma$,
$$g(x,y,\sigma)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}exp(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}),$$
and $x,y,\sigma$ are of the same dimension $L$, so I guess in $g$, the term $exp(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2})$ is dimensionless, isn't it? And the term $\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}$ is of dimension $L^{-2}$, right? So $g$ is actually of dimension $L^{-2}$, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Pure functions such as $\exp$, $\sin$, $\ln$ etc. are always dimensionless - they return $c$-numbers with no units attached. Since $\sigma$ is a length, you can indeed conclude that $[g] = L^{-2}.$

Comment: Finally someone answered my question, thank you so much, you're the light in the dark, ;-). I wish I could upvote your answer, but I can't since my reputation is just $1$. Get back to the question, $LoG$ should have dimension $L^{-4}$, right? In order to make $LoG$ dimensionless, I should multiply it by $\sigma^4$, right?

Comment: Yes. The derivatives also have dimension $L^{-2}$, so the dimension of what you call $LoG$ is $L^{-4}.$

Comment: Also if you're happy with an answer, you can accept it - that way it will appear as such in the list of questions on the main page and other people won't waste time writing new answers.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any intuitive introduction or tutorial on dimensional analysis and non-dimensionalization, could you please give me some reference?

Comment: I went to look at my old course notes and it pointed to books by Barenblatt - Scaling, Self-similarity, and Intermediate Asymptotics, Sedov - Similarity and dimensional methods and Bridgman - Dimensional analysis (Yale Univ. Press). But I haven't read either of these books.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, when and why should we make an equation or operator dimensionless?

Comment: That's a long story but the most important reason is to simplify/improve the analysis of a problem. It might seem that some phenomenom depends on many different dimensionful parameters, but often we can scale away most of these and are left with one or two dimensionless ones. Take the harmonic oscillator: it seems to depend on the mass $M$ and spring constant $K$, but really only the frequency $\omega = \sqrt{K/M}$ counts. You can make the time dimensionless ($T = \omega t$) and then you only have the ODE $y''(T) + y(T) = 0$ to solve.

Comment: I'm back with one more question, the Laplacian operator is the sum of 2nd-order derivatives, so it has dimension $L^{-2}$, multiplying $\sigma^2$ can make it dimensionless, but different $\sigma$ will result into different dimensionless Laplacian operator, I wonder how could I compare them with each other?

Comment: Well, in your problem $\sigma$ is something you put in by hand, probably because of some boundary conditions or parameters of the problem. The Laplacian itself doesn't depend on any particular scale.